# Rails 3 Routes: How do you show a nested page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to show the first page from a lesson when I click on the show link

Here is what I have:

**Lesson index:**

```
<%= link_to 'Show', lesson_page_path(lesson)%><br />
```

**Pages Controller**

```
def show
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  @first_page = @lesson.pages.first

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @page }
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :lessons do
  resources :pages
end
```

**I am getting this error**

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages", :lesson_id=># Lesson id: 1, title: ...

**How can I get to this url when I click on the show link:**

/lessons//pages/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're nesting like that, you need to link to both a page and a lesson:

```
lesson_page_path(lesson, page)
```

If you just want the first one, define another route:

```
get '/lesson/:lesson_id/page_one', :to => "pages#show"
```